# GWT AutoBean with POJO class instead of interface

Tags: json, gwt, serialization, autobean

I'm hoping someone can suggest a simple solution to my problem.

I have a POJO, say:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
}
```

I'd like to use GWT's AutoBean functionality to serialize / deserialize this bean to JSON, but AutoBean expects an interface:

```
public interface Person
{
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
}
```

I have an AutoBeanFactory setup:

```
public interface PersonFactory extends AutoBeanFactory
{
    AutoBean<Person> person();
}
```

Using the factory and the Person interface, I am able to deserialize a JSON Person:

```
PersonFactory personFactory = GWT.create(PersonFactory.class);
AutoBean<Person> autoBeanPerson = AutoBeanCodex.decode(personFactory, Person.class, jsonObject.toString());
Person person = autoBeanPerson.as();
```

However, if I replace the Person interface with the Person class, I receive an AutoBeanFactoryGenerator exception that states: "com.xxx.xxx.Person is not an interface".

How can I use AutoBean serialization / deserialization with my simple POJO?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply can't. AutoBean generates lightweight, optimized implementations of the interfaces; it obviously cannot do this for classes. This is *by design*.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible if its a simple POJO and does not have properties of other autobean types:

1) Make `PersonPojo implements Person`

2) Add a wrapper method to the factory:

```
public interface PersonFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    AutoBean<Person> person( Person p ); // wrap existing
}
```

3) Create wrapped AutoBean and serialise with `AutoBeanCodex.encode` to JSON

```
PersonPojo myPersonPojo = new PersonPojo("joe");
AutoBean<Person> autoBeanPerson = personFactory.person( myPersonPojo );
```

Comment: Isn't it possible in case of decoding?

Comment: @NaveedS Not sure what you mean, care to elaborate?

Comment: Isn't it possible to decode like `AutoBeanCodex.decode(personFactory, PersonPojo.class, jsonObject.toString());`?

Comment: It isn't, that was the original problem in the question.