# Serialize POJO with Pure GWT

Tags: java, json, gwt

What could be wrong with my code:

```
String serializeToJson(MyModel model) {
    // Retrieve the AutoBean controller
    AutoBean<MyModel> bean = AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(model);
    return AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
}
```

Even the model object is not null and the values/fields are set. The returned `String` is `null`.

Comment: Is MyModel an interface? How did you create your MyModel instance? Please post enough code to do more than guess at what might be wrong.

Comment: MyModel is a concrete class, and model is an instance of MyModel with fields and values set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autobeans work with interfaces, that *only* declare getter and setter methods. While you can create a concrete instance of that class, it has no `AutoBean<MyModel>` representation, so you can't get the magic serialization, at least not easily.

This is *not* a magic DWIM serialization tool - it is a way to describe data that looks like Java objects, but is backed by whatever makes the most sense for your use case. Things that are possible with Java objects (like cycles in your objects, polymorphism, etc) are not possible with AutoBeans, they are simply not designed for it, and if anything they are designed to *not* be able to do this.

Check the result from `AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean` in your code above - it is probably returning `null`, since there is no `AutoBean` in your `MyModel` instance.

See [GWT AutoBean with POJO class instead of interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261682/gwt-autobean-with-pojo-class-instead-of-interface) for another discussion around this question, and http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html for how to use autobeans correctly.

Comment: So there is no possible solution to serialize a GWT POJO with pure GWT?

Comment: How about this one: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.extjs/gxt/2.0.1/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/js/JsonConverter.java

Comment: 'So there is no possible solution...?' No, there are solutions, but this isn't it. Don't ask 'can A do B?' if you want to know 'can B be done?'. The linked code should be obviously not suited to this tasks from reading the method signature - it returns a `Map<String, Object>`. GWT RPC is one such tool that *can* serialize POJOs, Piriti is another, and Errai has its own mechanism as well.